# The system cannot find the file specified Python

Tags: python

I am trying to load a file in python while using th pylab package. I have tried to copy and paste the path but I am still getting this error. I am using the !type function and the file name, however I get the following error "The system cannot find the file specified.
Error occurred while processing: C:\Users\user\Desktop\Downloads\Other-Types-Of-Plots-Codefiles\New.
The system cannot find the file specified.
Error occurred while processing: Folder"

Comment: Show us your code!

Answer (score 0):

use 'path', the quotation marks.

Comment: The code is !type file name. I have tried using the path as well still I am getting the same error.